# Use mediawiki functions in code

Tags: php, xml, parsing, mediawiki

I have mediawiki installed and configured on my machine. I want to use the parse() function in a php script I'm writing in order to convert xml from a file to html. I currently have it working using the meidawiki API, but I want to use mediawiki itself that I've installed, instead of calling the API and using that. How can I use the functions that the mediawiki install provides? (New to this whole thing)

Answer (score 1):

The MediaWiki Parser class has a lot of dependencies, you're probably better off just using the Mediawiki API if you really need to parse text.